# Let Parent View child's result

Tags: 7, views

I need to setup a view for a parent which shows the result of his child. The result is a content type which has a user reference field to each student who owns the result.

Each students' profile has a user reference field to his /her parent username. I.m using profile 2 to setup parent and children account differently.

By using contextual filter and relationships, I can easily show the fields of the result to each student who owns the result but since parents' account are different, I really don't know how to show contents linked to individual student to show in their parent account.

Answer (score 0):

- Download and install the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module
- In parent user fields, add a field with **Entity Reference** and a widget of **Auto complete (tag style)**

For example: I named mine lalala (click picture below to enlarge)

[image]

- For Target Type, select **User**
- Number of Values: **Unlimited** (as parent could have more than 1 child)

[image]

- Then go to the parents account and start typing child's account user name, you will see the name in the drop down, select it and save.

Use a comma `,` to add other child account. (parent has more than 1 child)

[image]

### In your view

- contextual filter of User id (uid) (which uses the parent's id)
- add a **relationship** of lalala Referenc**ed** Entity

  - If not, try Referenc**ing** entity, but if my memory is correct it's Referenc**ed**

Comment: Wao! Letme quickly try that. Will get back to you now. Thanks

Comment: @primerater01 how did it go?

Comment: I actualy employed another method which worked perfectly the way i want it. Bt i tried ur approach and it did work too. Thank you.

Comment: Could u share me ur email or facebook name if u dnt mind please?

Comment: I rather that you msg me here and then we can use the chat if we need to :-) http://chat.stackexchange.com/